# MYSQL: Transfer values from one table to another based on date/hour

Tags: mysql, date, time, transfer

i have the following MYSQL tables:

Part of the input table 'input':

[image: Input Table]

and part of the Output Table 'output':

[image: Output table]

both date/time columns are pre given and cannot be changed. they are the basis of the MYSQL code I want to use to do the following:
I want to sum all values from 'total' column of the input table from the **same date and same hour** and put them into 'total' column of the output table where the 'time' column has the **same date and same hour** as in the input table.

**Would this be possible with MYSQL only?**
Or do I need PHP as well?
The input table has about 400,000 values.

I started with:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM input
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-06-06 00:00:00' AND '2019-06-06 23:59:59'
```

But I dont know how to continue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: your input and output date don't match  ...  you should provide a clear expected result  based on your data  sample .. (you should avoid post image and you shuold post data sample as tabular text)

Comment: @scaisEdge the image only shows part of the table. it continues through many days after the ones you see. thats why i need to compare date and hour.

Comment: ... we can understand  your question only with the element you post  ..  if the question is not clear  .. ..is difficult find a solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the sums in the input table and join to the output table in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update output o 
inner join (
  select date_format(date, '%Y%m%d%H') hour, sum(total) total
  from input
  group by date_format(date, '%Y%m%d%H')
) i on i.hour = date_format(o.date, '%Y%m%d%H')
set o.total = i.total
```

Comment: WOW. fast answer and worked instantly!! Thank you so much. I didnt know inner join could be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE outputtable,
       (SELECT Sum(total)  SUM,
                Year(date)  year,
                Month(date) month,
                Day(date)   day,
                Hour(date)  hour
         FROM   inputtable
         GROUP  BY Year(date),
                   Month(date),
                   Day(date),
                   Hour(date)) InputT SET    total = InputT.sum WHERE  Year(outputtable.date) = InputT.year
        AND Month(outputtable.date) = InputT.month
        AND Day(outputtable.date) = InputT.day
        AND Hour(outputtable.date) = InputT.hour;
```